# App crash when hitting back Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a strange issue where when I hit back (returning to UIViewController I had pushed from), my app crashes. It seems something is sending a message to my deallocated UIViewController (the one being popped).

I think the message being sent is UIViewHierachy Subviews. I do have code in both VCs that called `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but commenting this out did not help.

When I add an exception breakpoint, my app crashes when launching! Is this a storyboard issue or something in my code?

Crash log says :

`2015-02-05 12:37:26.255 FitSpot[46915:6318736] *** -[TrainerCreateNewAccountViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f988636ad40`

[image: Zombies]

Comment: could you please post the crashlog :)

Comment: @nburk sure one sec :)

Comment: @nburk. I think its an autolayout issue. I reset my constraints for one VC and its working now. I have a duplicate VC and that isn't working so I'll try that method. Damn AL !

Comment: it seems your `TrainerCreateNewAccountViewController` has been deallocated. when and how do you use this one?

Comment: @nburk See my answer below. I fixed this but unsure of why this fix worked. `TrainerCreateNewAccountViewController` is the a similar VC to of `CustomerCreateNewAccountViewController` (I copied it from storyboard and then created the VC and renamed it). I'm not sure if I was seguging back from `TrainerCreateNewAccountViewController` or `CustomerCreateNewAccountViewController` that time, but if its `CustomerCreateNewAccountViewController` than that is strange that it was sending a message to the other VC.

Comment: @nburk Removing the following lines worked.  `self.myUITextField.delegate = self;` I was defining these in two similar VCs. I have no idea why segueing back would crash the app. Maybe hitting the back also registered my resign first responder but this was being called after my VC dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out quickly copying and pasting code was my problem:

```
    self.emailSignUpField.layer.delegate = self;
```

Forgot to remove the layer portion line